# Suppressing sections if another section is not suppressed in crystal report c# 4.0

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, crystal-reports, c#-3.0

i am working on a report (crystal report) in which i have multiple page headers.

The part i am stuck in is that if

1) **PageHeaderSection (a)** is not suppressed then **PageHeaderSection (b)** gets suppressed and

2) if **PageHeaderSection (b)** is not suppressed then **PageHeaderSection (a**) gets suppressed.

please help me with the above situation as i am unable to find where to apply the code in crystal report and what the code should be to do the above work.

Thanks in advance

**Edit**

here is an image how the crystal report looks

https://www.dropbox.com/s/bcocp5stn0pzvwe/Untitled.png?dl=0

Comment: Can you show a code example of what you have (in your question, not the comment section)?

Comment: What is your supress condition?

Comment: as mentioned in the question if my pageheader(a) is not suppressed then pageheader(b) should get suppressed

Answer (score 0):

try this:

if suppose your `field1` is the field that you are trying to use for supress.

in `Page header a`

```
if field1=somevalue //your comparision value
then true
else false
```

in `Page header b`

```
if field1=somevalue //your comparision value
then false
else true
```

Comment: no i need it for the whole section not for the field as the section has about 20 fields in it

Comment: Solution is for whole section not for the single field....field is involved in supression formula

Comment: can you change the comparision with if the particular section is suppressed or not

Comment: Write the formula in the section expert of the pageheader a and b.... if you find it difficult post your formula will change formula in the solution aswell

Comment: no i cannot understand where to write your formula and the above formula 's condition should be if the section is suppressed or not. now can you help?

Comment: Right click section and then go to section expert there go to page heade a and there click the formula x-2 at supress and write the condition and follow same process for page header b aswell

Comment: that is obvious but what will be the condition to check if the section is suppressed or not?

Comment: As a developer you should be aware of what condition to be used... how would i know

Comment: that is the problem here i don't know what condition to put so to check if page header (a) is suppressed or not

Comment: Dude that the primary requirement you need to know the condition.. if as a developer you don't know the condition then who can tell you.